# Xcode switching between git and svn on project that has both

Tags: xcode, git, svn

I'm working on a project that is stored in a Subversion repository. I want to use git locally to avoid committing incomplete features.

When I first init the git repository, start Xcode and make some changes, it switches its indicators to the git status. I can git commit from the command line and Xcode will reflect that.

However, doing a commit using the Xcode dialog makes Xcode switch the indicators to show the Subversion status again.

Is there a way to tell Xcode to use git and ignore Subversion?

I'm using Xcode 4.3

Answer (score 0):

git-svn should solve this for you by allowing your to work only in git and committing your changes to the SVN repo through git commands.

[A sample setup is described here](http://geppyparziale.com/post/7051869663) and I've found [this tutorial](http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/) helpful to get started with git-svn

Comment: OK I guess this is the "right" way to do it. However, I'd like Xcode to properly handle the situation where I have both .git and .svn folders inside my project. It seems to get confused in such case.

Comment: I don't use Xcode actively, but I suspect supporting your (arguably corner-case) usage won't be high on their list of priorities. Good luck.

Comment: Luckily it is a one-off deal. When I'm finished with this feature we're switching the whole project to git anyway.